# The AJAX and JSON code is unable to fetch data from database

Tags: php, json, ajax

This particular code is unable to fetch data from the MYSQL database. And if I am trying to print the value of select option using the javascript it is giving undefined value..

```js
<h1> How to retrieve data using JSON and AJAX </h1>
  <select name="details_list" id="details list">
   <option value=""> Select Name </option>
   <?php 
     while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
     echo '<option value="'.$row["name"].'">'.$row["name"].'</option>';  
  }
   ?>
 </select>
<button type="button" name="search" id="search"> Search </button>
  <p id="user_name"></p>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function()
  {
   $('#search').click(function() 
   {
   var id= $('#details_list').val();
  if(id != '')
  {
    $.ajax({
    url:"fetch.php",
    method:"POST",
    data:{id:id},
    dataType:"JSON",
    success:function(data)
    {
     $('#user_name').text(data.name); 
    }
         })
  }
  else
  {
   alert("Please Select Employee");
   $('#employee_details').css("display", "none");
  }
   
      });
  });
    

 </script>`
```

Comment: How can we help you? What is the problem exactly?

Comment: The problem is the select tag is not passing any information to the ajax code and this code 'var id= $('#details_list').val()' is setting the value of id as undefined. All the databse values and php scripts are correct just this <select> tag is giving problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<select name="details_list" id="details_list">` instead of `<select name="details_list" id="details list">`.

You can get value by using two steps

```
1>  `id= $('#details_list option:selected').text()`
2>  `id= $('#details_list').val()`
```

If you use above code then you will resolved your undefined value issue.

Comment: thankyou very much , and yes val() is working fine and text() is not working , I'll go with val().And thankyou it worked

Answer (score 1):

The html for the `SELECT` has an `id` of `details list` but in the javascript you reference an `id` of `details_list`

So change

```
<select name="details_list" id="details list">
```

to

```
<select name="details_list" id="details_list">
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line:

```
<select name="details_list" id="details list">
```

You have a space in the `id` instead of an underscore.